# android studio use sync project with gradle files action

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

I want to use **sync project with gradle file** in command line but I dont know how to do

like this :

[image]

It besides do `./gradlew build` also do other things

For example, in a file is written to a local library name **android-test**
than in **settings.gradle** read this file and call **include ":${android-test}"** .if I use AS **sync project with gradle files** button，AS can load
module to project , but when I run **./gradlew build**, it doesn't work.

But I have developed a plugins, and I want to use this action, so how to call this function ?

Answer (score 0):

[Building and syncing from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) is really simple. In the root of your project you can invoke the gradle wrapper's build command with

```
./gradlew build
```

To get a list of all available build tasks for your project:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

"./gradlew build" and "./gradlew tasks" in the path of your project.
more commands and steps here:https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

The action id is `Android.SyncProject`, so you can call it in your plugin:

```java
ActionManager.getInstance().getAction("Android.SyncProject").actionPerformed(e);
```

> You can find it in [android-plugin.xml](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/android/src/META-INF/android-plugin.xml), maybe line `161`.
>
> Also in [SyncProjectAction.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/gradle/actions/SyncProjectAction.java), line `36` you can find its text.